# How do I check if a port is open between two Linux servers?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, port, iptables

How do you check if a port is open when you cannot use telnet or install Cacti?  I want to see if a port is open between two Linux servers.  Telnet isn't installed.  I tried this command:

```
cat < /dev/tcp/x.x.x.x/6061
```

where x.x.x.x was the remote IP address of the Linux server and port 6061 is the port that I want to test.  But based on tests of known working and not working ports, this command wasn't conclusive to me.  There may be an environmental explanation for that.

Answer (score 2):

Install nmap and than:

```
nmap x.x.x.x
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use (if installed) : [netcat](/questions/tagged/netcat) :

```
nc -zw3 <host> <port>
```

If you want to use the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) feature *net redirection* :

```
cat < /dev/tcp/x.x.x.x/6061
```

do it the right way :

```
{ exec 3<> /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/6061; } &>/dev/null &&
    echo "Connection to socket OK" ||
    echo >&2 "Can't connect"
```

If it doesn't work, you need to compile [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) with `--enable-net-redirections`

Comment: nc wasn't installed.  Thanks anyway.